# Unable to resolve module multer

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I'm getting an error when a run my react-native project in Android device.

I already tried many things. Remove node_modules, `clear npm cache`, yarn too, use yarn and npm to install, and don't resolve it.

What is happening?

> ```
> Error: Unable to resolve module `util` from `node_modules/multer/lib/multer-error.js`: util could not be found within the project.
>
> If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
>  1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
>  2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
>  3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
>  4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
> ```

Already tried the suggestions indicated in the error message too.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "svm",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-ftp": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-youtube": "^2.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "ssh2-sftp-client": "^5.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.28.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-sftp": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multer is listed as dev dependency. I guess you have build the app for production when testing it. So the package is not loaded.

Moving the "multer": "^1.4.2" dependency to "dependencies" from "devDependencies" should probably resolve it.